# Aplicação foi rejeitada na Apple Store devido a diferença de idioma com as mensagens do IOS

Tags: ionic, ios

Subi uma aplicação para a Loja da Apple, pra ser instalada no iPhone e recebi a rejeição da mesma por conta de uma coisa estranha:

> Guideline 4.0 - Design
>
> We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user experience than Apple users expect:
>
> > Your app's modal alerts are in English, but your app's primary language is Portuguese. To help users understand why your app is requesting access to a specific feature, your app's modal alerts should be in the same language as the rest of your app.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to address all instances of this type of issue.
>
> Resources
>
> For information on improving and enhancing your app:
>
> - Watch the video The Ingredients of Great Apps to understand the basics of great apps.
> - Watch the video iPhone and iPad User Interface Design for practical design tips.
> - Watch iOS Development Videos to learn about programming and design tips.
> - Review the iOS Human Interface Guidelines and ensure that your app's interface and design adhere to these guidelines.
>
> Please see attached screenshot for details.

A aplicação é em português, desenvolvida no Ionic 1 versão 3.16.0. A mensagem que surge é aquela solicitando ao proprietário do aparelho para permitir que o app acesse a sua localização. Só que esta estava em inglês, e esse foi o motivo da rejeição. É um alert do Sistema Operacional do dispositivo e não da minha aplicação.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2):

Você deve adicionar no arquivo `config.xml`, na seção platform, [as permissões](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list?language=objc) que você usa junto com as mensagens adequadas. Um exemplo:

```
<platform name="ios">
    ...
    <config-file parent="NSLocationUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>Precisamos da sua localização para ...</string>
    </config-file>
    ....
</platform>
```